# Given rank($A$) = rank$(A^{2})$, can we prove A is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove, given rank($A$) = rank($A^{2}$), that Nul(A) = Nul($A^{2}$), and that the intersection of the column space of A and the null space of A is the set containing the zero vector. If I can show that rank($A$) = rank($A^{2}$) implies A is invertible, my goals become much easier.

So first of all is my approach correct? Assuming it is, how can I prove rank($A$) = rank($A^{2}$) implies there exists $A^{-1}$?

Comment: The theorem you want to use (if it's at your disposal) is the Rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: But using that we have that the nullity of A is equal to the nullity of A^2, does it follow that the null space of A is equal to the null space of A^2?

Comment: My apologies. I assumed that 'Nul' meant nullity, as in here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-nullity_theorem. I haven't seen anyone represent the null space by 'Nul'; I usually see 'ker' or occasionaly 'Null'.

Comment: But you can still use the rank-nullity theorem paired with some basic facts about finite dimensions. You can see that $\ker A\subseteq \ker A^2$. I'm assuming your ambient space is finite-dimensional. Since we already saw the dimension of these two spaces are the same, what does that tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a projector then $A^2 = A$. But $A$ does not have to be invertible.

**Hint:** $A$ restricted to $Im(A)$ is a linear application whose null space is
$null(A)\cap Im(A)$.

Comment: right, I see that now after checking that with a non-invertible matrix and still getting that the rank of A is equal to the rank of A^2.